# DELL restore not working

Tags: windows-vista, dell-xps

I have the Dell XPS M1330 and it came with Windows Vista Home pre-installed but I did a stupid thing and installed Vista Professional over it now I can't restore it to its previous state.

I can still see the restore drive but I can't seem to restore it?  Any tips?

I want to restore it back to factory settings.

EDIT:  When I reboot and press F8 I don't have any options for repairing my PC - boot to windows etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Vista Professional may have just overwritten the boot menu which contained the option to boot into the recovery partition.

You may be able to use [**EasyBCD**](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) to search for the recovery partition, add it back into the boot menu and then boot into it as you were trying to do.